# Set data to Sharepoint Gridview from List and remove appropriate selected columns

Tags: 2010, jquery, splistitem

I am using c# and I have a `SPList` with fields such **Title** and **Translation**. I want to set **Word** and **Translation** into `SPGridview`.

I can retrieve data from my List:

```
string translation = (string)itemfields["Translation"];
string word = (string)itemfields["Title "];
```

So, I need put it into `SPGridview` and if user selects right variant of **word - translation**  to change background color and delete from table. Of course  **word - translation** should be in different(random) position (in different 'tr' ). Any useful link will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for getting items from the `SPList` to the `GridView`, do an `SPQuery` for the items you want to display. Once you have the `SPListItemCollection` from the query, get the `DataTable` from it and bind to the `GridView`.

```
DataTable table = items.GetDataTable();
GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks! I ve used following and it solved my problem `var spQuery = new SPQuery();
                   SPFolder folder = list.RootFolder.SubFolders[ListSelectedFolder];
                   spQuery.Folder = folder;
                   SPListItemCollection FolderItems = list.GetItems(spQuery);

                   table = new DataTable();

                   table.Columns.Add("Words");
                   table.Columns.Add("Translations"); .................               GameRepeater.DataSource = table;
                               GameRepeater.DataBind(); `

Comment: Glad it helped. Also, on Stack Exchange sites, please do not forget to mark answers as accepted if they helped. This lets other people know that the answer works and is correct.